# Celula de Table Desloca Sozinha

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, table, tabela-html

Tenho uma tabela que carrega uma lista de dados, porém no IE (de vez em quando) algumas células se deslocam para fora da tabela. Isso começou a ocorrer quando iniciei a utilização do bootstrap.

Alguém pode ajudar?

Segue um print:

[image: Células estourando limite da tabela]

Comment: Coloca o código e diz qual a versão do IE...

Comment: Provavelmente existem mais células naquela linha, do que nas outras ou alguma célula está com `colspan` que supera o número de colunas. Ou alguma má formatação de tags (alguma tag não foi fechada corretamente.). Como disse o Rafael, coloque seu código na pergunta clicando em [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/81938/edit) logo a baixo da sua pergunta, assim poderemos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Tem alguma tag <td></td> sobrando antes da sua <td><select .... 1,00 ... </td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com certeza se trata de um erro na construção da tabela. A Tabela, como no excel por exemplo, precisa ter linhas e colunas que estejam perfeitamente alinhadas, uma linha com 4 colunas e outra com 6 faria com que esse erro ocorre-se. Eu te aconselho a indentar o código corretamente que ficará bem mais fácil de localizar uma tag mal fechada ou um problema de lógica na construção da tabela.